# Failed template argument deduction when using template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I wanted to create a simple auxiliary algorithm that would fill a container, such as `std::vector<T>`, with a geometric progression (the first term is `a`, and the `n`-th term is given by `a * pow(r, n-1)`, where `r` is a given ratio); I created the following code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

template<template <typename> class Container, typename T>
void progression(Container<T>& container, T a, T ratio, size_t N) {
  if(N > 0) {    
    T factor = T(1);  
    for(size_t k=0; k<N; k++) {
      container.push_back(a * factor);
      factor *= ratio;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> r;
  progression(r, 10.0, 0.8, static_cast<size_t>(10));

  for(auto item : r) {
    std::cout<<item<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

which yields the following errors upon attempting compilation:

```
$ g++ geometric.cpp -std=c++11 # GCC 4.7.2 on OS X 10.7.4
geometric.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
geometric.cpp:18:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘progression(std::vector<double>&, double, double, size_t)’
geometric.cpp:18:52: note: candidate is:
geometric.cpp:6:6: note: template<template<class> class Container, class T> void progression(Container<T>&, T, T, size_t)
geometric.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
geometric.cpp:18:52: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
geometric.cpp:5:36: error: provided for ‘template<class> class Container’
```

Clang's error message is more subtle:

```
$ clang++ geometric.cpp -std=c++11 # clang 3.2 on OS X 10.7.4 
geometric.cpp:18:3: error: no matching function for call to 'progression'
  progression(r, 10, 0.8, 10);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
geometric.cpp:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
void progression(Container<T>& container, T a, T ratio, size_t N) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I would have expected that using template template parameters I would be able to deduce not only the container, but also the container's `value_type` (`T` in this case).

So, the question is: **how can I create a generic function which will be able to deduce both the container type and the value type?**

I am sure I'm missing something obvious - I appreciate your patience and help.

## Edit (Answer)

The following code behaves as expected:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

template<template <typename...> class Container, typename T, typename... Args>
void progression(Container<Args...>& container, T a, T ratio, size_t N) {
  if(N > 0) {    
    T factor = T(1);  
    for(size_t k=0; k<N; k++) {
      container.push_back(a * factor);
      factor *= ratio;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> r;
  progression(r, 10.0, 0.8, 10);

  for(auto item : r) {
    std::cout<<item<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
8
6.4
5.12
4.096
3.2768
2.62144
2.09715
1.67772
1.34218
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **first problem** is, that you are forgetting that `std::vector<>` is a class template accepting *two* template parameters (the element type and the allocator), not one. The fact that the second template parameter has a default value is irrelevant when you are using template template parameters:

```
template<template <typename, typename> class Container, typename T, typename A>
//                           ^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^
void progression(Container<T, A>& container, T a, T ratio, size_t N) {
//                         ^^^^
// ...
}
```

Notice, that this will make it impossible to pass, for instance, an instance of `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` as the first function argument. Therefore, my suggestion is to give up *deducing* that the first argument is the instance of a standard container (standard containers are just not that uniform):

```
template<typename C, typename T, typename A>
//       ^^^^^^^^^
void progression(C& container, T a, T ratio, size_t N) {
//               ^^
// ...
}
```

What you may want to do then is to express the compile-time *constrain*, perhaps through a `static_assert` and based on a custom type trait, that `C` must be an instance of a standard container.

Alternatively, you can use variadic templates [as suggested by KerrekSB in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864544/1932150) (but that still won't prevent you from passing in an instance of any other kind of template, even non-container ones).

The **second problem** is in the way you are calling your template:

```
progression(r, 10, 0.8, 10);
```

Here, the type of the second argument is `int`, while the type of the container element is `double`. This will confuse the compiler when performing type deduction. Either call it this way:

```
progression(r, 10.0, 0.8, 10);
```

Or allow your compiler to deduce a different type for the second argument (possible SFINAE-constraining it to be something that can convert to the element type).

Comment: I actually have an improved version of this answer, but my network connection went down and I cannot edit from my mobile(it's just a mess).

Answer (score 4):

Containers usually have a lot of template arguments. Fortunately, there's a special clause in variadic templates that lets use use a pack for any concrete number of arguments:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename ...Args>
void foo(Container<Args...> const & c)
{
    // ...
}
```

(The special clause effects that this works even when `Container` is a non-variadic template.)

Comment: This is not a variadic template

Comment: I never thought about doing this. That's neat.

Comment: Thank you - the final implementation uses the syntax you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is failing is because you are saying middle two args are the same type when they are actually not. For example the middle is a float while the other is an int. Basically you are saying a and ratio are the same type but in the call they are different types

Comment: I think you meant that the middle is a `double` and that the one before it should be as well.

Comment: Look at my edits - this is not the problem. Even if I pass two `double`s and cast the integer as `size_t` the problem remains.

Comment: @aaronman - it was in fact a problem  - after I removed the first bug, the error you describe did show up.

Comment: @Arrieta unfortunately I can't answer the second problem can you explain the syntax of the template