# nested templates function taking 2 containers with the same inner type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write function which is roughly similar to a function that takes two instances of containers (let's say for now they are the same), containing same type and merges them.  So here's my function for vectors:

```
template<typename T>
void test(std::vector<T> v1, std::vector<T> v2) {
  std::cout << "called nested for c\n";
}
```

and it works.

Now I want to have one that would work for sets or vectors.  And I try this:

```
template<typename T, template <typename> typename C >
void test(C<T> v1, C<T> v2) {
  std::cout << "called nested for c<t>\n";
}
```

and get

> nestedt.cc:33:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution
>   failed: nestedt.cc:43:12: error: wrong number of template arguments
>   (3, should be 1)    test(s, s);
>               ^ nestedt.cc:32:51: note: provided for ‘template class C’  template typename C >
>                                                      ^

I try

```
template< template <typename T> typename C >
void test(C<T> v1, C<T> v2) {}

std::set<int> s = {1,2};
test(s, s);
```

and that doesn't work:

> nestedt.cc:32:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution
>   failed: nestedt.cc:42:12: note:   cannot convert ‘s’ (type
>   ‘std::set’) to type ‘int’    test(s, s);
>               ^

So I try

```
template<typename C, typename T >
void test(C<T> v1, C<T> v2) {}
```

and get

> nestedt.cc:32:6: note: candidate: template void
>   test(C, C)  void test(C v1, C v2) {
>         ^ nestedt.cc:32:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: nestedt.cc:42:12: note:   couldn't
>   deduce template parameter ‘T’    test(s, s);
>               ^

I feel like I'm not even close to understanding how templates actually work in C++ and it is so sad.
Also in reality I want the containers to be different.  And ideally be able to somehow specify a limited set of allowed containers.  And they are not really std:: containers.

Note that the final goal is to be able to take 2 different containers, so something like `test(vector<int>, set<int>)`.  And modifying the containers is kind of impossible.

Comment: Why not just `template<typename C>void test(C v1, C v2) {}`?

Comment: Because I really want test(<C1<T> v1, C2<T> v2), 2 different containers containing the same values.

Comment: They would be.  You wouyld be able to call `test(vector<int>, set<int>)`.  It would only compile if the same container type is used.  I think I get where you are going though and will write up an answer that will show you how you can constrain the template.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you misread.  I want to allow it to be called with different containers.

Comment: Passing an iterator would suffice for the function's purpose? Suppose you're using std::vector and std::list, they implement ForwardIterator and you can use the post-increment operator on it.

Comment: Both containers implement similar enough interfaces but no inheritance and there are no iterators.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but similar question which provides an answer, at least for the `std::vector` container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864476/failed-template-argument-deduction-when-using-template-template-parameters The `std::set` may be similar...

Comment: Maybe just use SFINAE to put a restriction that the content types are the same?  Something like `template <typename C1, typename C2> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename C1::value_type, typename C2::value_type>, void> test(const C1& v1, const C2& v2)`

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
template<template <typename...> typename Cont1, 
         template <typename...> typename Cont2,
         typename... T>
void test(Cont1<T...> a, Cont2<T...> b) { }
```

In the above `template <typename...> typename Cont1` declares one template template type and `template <typename...> typename Cont2` declares another one so you can have two different container types.  The both share `T...` so each template container needs to have a matching template parameter list.  This means

```
test(std::map<int, int>{}, std::map<int, int>{});
test(std::set<int>{}, std::set<int>{});
test(std::vector<int>{}, std::set<int>{});
```

all work but

```
test(std::map<int, int>{}, std::vector<int>{});
test(std::map<int, int>{}, std::set<int>{});
```

wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need at least 2 template parameters:

1. Container type
2. Contained type

Since you're using an STL container and **passing the contained type apart from the container**, the compiler **cannot infer** the other parameters (e.g., allocator `std::allocator<T>`, compare `std::less<T>`). But you can forward all nested templated parameters using a variadic template. Example:

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... T>
struct wrapper {
    typedef C<T...> type;
};
wrapper<std::vector, int>::type foo;
wrapper<std::set   , int>::type bar;
```

You can [see it in ideone](https://www.ideone.com/46cM6D).

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was nearly right. You got the error because the standard containers like `vector` accept more than one template parameter. For example, this is `std::vector`:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

You never usually use the second parameter, and it has a default, but it's still present, so your template template parameter `template <typename> typename C` can't match. Instead, you can do this:

```
template<template <typename...> typename C, typename... Ts>
void test(C<Ts...> v1, C<Ts...> v2) {}
```